# X-Ray mode in lookdev view, Blender 2.8

Tags: image

I'm trying to model using a reference image, so I'd like to see though the cylinder so I can see the image. The problem is that, even with the X-Ray button activated, I can't get it transparent in lookdev viewport mode. As you can see from the images below, the x-ray mode works as it should in solid viewport mode, but not in lookdev. As I require to use the lookdev mode to see the image, I can't use the solid mode (at least as far as I know)

Is there any way to make the cylinder less opaque so I can see the reference plane and work on it?

[image: Solid shading view]

[image: LookDev view]

Comment: For Loook Dev, from the  Viewport Overlays dropdown menu, under Shading enable the Hidden Wire, Option.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I can't find that option in that menu.